# Auth 2.0 provider implementation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, provider

I have a web application in ruby and I want it to act as a Auth 2.0 provider. Are there any such provider implementations available in ruby? If so, can anyone guide me on how to implement it in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper) is probably what you want to do, while [oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) is a wrapper for the OAuth 2.0 protocol.

More solutions are available on RubyGems if you search for [oauth](http://rubygems.org/search?query=oauth).